# Trying to build a dynamic stepper inside material dialog with reactive forms for a reusable 'automated' assistant component

Tags: angular, angular-material, reusability

So I'm trying to build an assistant that shows different steps depending on what data it received. That way I can reuse it for many different flows for every user type (who require individual steps for e.g. registration - sometimes 5 steps, sometimes 3 and so on).

For that I am using a stepper which has different content depending on the use case...

But for some reason my approach to do stuff similiar to this approach (https://georghoeller.dev/angular-material-dynamic-dialog-component/) failed! TLDR: I'm passing TemplateRefs into the dialog and display the content via [ngTemplateOutlet].

I don't know how I can make this scenario work! In react this would be very easy but angular really knows how to overcomplicate things...

Here is the url to my code so far https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zsdop-mfbfbx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: so every step will contain different set of questions?

Comment: Yes. A question or a prompt and then some kind of input element (checkbox, text, etc). Because someone who already has an e-mail needs to fill out different stuff (3 steps only) than someone who does not even have one (5 steps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FormArray` with respective `FormGroup` of different stepper

initialize your form array in ngOnInit and add diffrent screen/stepper formGrop according to logic something like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      form: this._formBuilder.array([this.initFormGroup(1)]),
    });

  }

initFormGroup(index: number) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1: {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
          type: 1,
          first: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          last: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        });
      }
      case 2: {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
          type: 2,
          address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        });
      }
      case 3: {
        // logic 
      }
    }
  }
```

then handle in each stepper html form logic according to form type value.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <mat-horizontal-stepper  formArrayName="form">
        <mat-step [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let elements of formGroup.controls.form.controls; let i = index">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Step {{i + 1}}</ng-template>
          <div *ngIf="getFormType(i) == 1">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input
                matInput
                placeholder="firstName"
                formControlName="first"
                required
              />
            </mat-form-field>
         </div>
         <div *ngIf="getFormType(i) == 2">
            <!- different form group html here -->
         </div>
        <div>
          <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
          <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
        </mat-step>
      </mat-horizontal-stepper>
    </form>
```

here is stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-cbw3bb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Ok, that looks good. I already feared that this won't work with ngTemplateOutlet but oh well I have to type out all the steps somewhere anyway.
But I think I will not use FormArray because in the end some backend api tells me what steps to display and in one scenario the "first" step might be a completely different one than in another scenario. So some kind of unique id to formgroup mapping needs to be implemented (instead of saying take scenario formType == 0).
Anyways, big thank you - I can continue to work with that! :)

Comment: that sounds great that it helps, i  added "type" because i was beliving sections form can be repeated but if not you can remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I realize now why ngTemplateOutlet was not working.. I'm calling my dialog via ngOnInit - at that time templates are not built yet! I should have called stuff in ngAfterViewInit!